# Entity Framework Complex Type property as key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is there a way in Entity Framework to use some complex type as key for an entity and map to existing database?

Let say I have database like this:

```
create table people ( id int, name nvarchar(128) )
```

and I'd like to map the following C# class structure to this table:

```
    class PersonId
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    class Person
    {
        public PersonId Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

How could I do that?

-Dmytro

Comment: Short answer: No key allowed in complex type properties and the complex type is not a key. Better answer: see Ted below for things that actually work. If you want to have a set of properties for all entity classes, you can use inheritance with table per concrete type. Maybe you can be more specific regarding your underlying design problem next to your not-working solution.

Answer (score 0):

What's the point of having a separate `PersonId` class if you only have on property? that seems like bad practice to me.

Perhaps all you need is a composite key. To use in in EF you can declare your class like this:

```
[Key, Column(Order = 0)]
public int column1 { get; set; }

[Key, Column(Order = 1)]
public int column2 { get; set; }
```

Comment: The intention I guess is strongly typed Id to prevent comparing apples to oranges, even though both addressed by integer number in the database

Comment: Thanks, Eugene. That's exactly the point of the question. For instance scala and go allows to create aliases for primitive types and the have compile time validation of identifiers passed around. An extra safe mechanism to avoid bugs related to misused IDs.